# Export and Import LDAP Schema

Tags: directory, openldap

Are there any standard tools for :

1. Exporting schema, entries
2. Importing schema, entries

Source: ds-389 directory

Destination: Openldap server

Answer (score 0):

Just a copy command. The schema files are available as LDIF in both servers.